# Kommasetzung bei „wäre es“

Tags: sentence-structure, comma

Ist die Kommasetzung im folgenden Satz korrekt (Komma vor und nach *wäre es*)?

> Eine Möglichkeit diesen Namenskonflikt aufzulösen, *wäre es*, die Elemente mit eindeutigen Präfixen zu versehen.

Um welches Konstrukt handelt es sich in diesem Beispiel? Zwei mittels *wäre es* verbundene Nebensätze?

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stack-Exchange der deutschen Sprache. Ich denke, du wirst von [tour] und [help] wissen, aber für alle Fälle bekommst du sie einmal auf dem Silbertablett geliefert ;)

Comment: @Jan Vielen Dank :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Erstmal die Satzstruktur: Es gibt hier keinen einzigen Nebensatz, nur Infinitivgruppen. Dies wird dadurch deutlich, dass es außer *wäre* kein konjugiertes Verb gibt.

Infinitivgruppen müssen dann mit einem Komma abgetrennt werden, wenn sie von einem Substantiv, Verweiswort oder Korrelat abhängen (§ 75) und keine einfachen Infinitive sind. Beides liegt hier vor:

- *diesen Namenskonflikt aufzulösen* hängt vom Substantiv *Möglichkeit* ab;
- *die Elemente mit eindeutigen Präfixen zu versehen* hängt vom Korrelat *es* ab.

Keine der Infinitivgruppen ist einfach. Deswegen müssen folgende **drei** Kommata gesetzt werden:

> Eine Möglichkeit**,** diesen Namenskonflikt aufzulösen**,** wäre es**,** die Elemente mit eindeutigen Präfixen zu versehen.

Der Satz lässt sich auch so umgestalten, dass keine Kommata nötig sind (aber möglich):

> Die Elemente mit eindeutigen Präfixen zu versehen(,) ist eine Möglichkeit zur Auflösung dieses Namenskonflikts.